# Cannot insert images in body of a basic page

Tags: 8, media, wysiwyg

I am using CKEditor and WYSIWYG. After updating Drupal core to 8.5.6, I cannot upload an image using the CKEditor's 'image' button anymore saying "Image Field is required."

[image]

[image]

I have checked CKEditor's plugin settings. Image upload's enabled there.

[image]

I have not found a solution yet. Any help will be appreciated.

PS: If I add an image using html "img" tag then it shows up properly, it's only the button that is not working properly.

Comment: Have you updated all your other modules?

Comment: Yes. Every module has been updated.

Comment: Have you tried the Imce file manager module?
https://www.drupal.org/project/imce
I have struggled with CK Editor in the past earlier D8 cores but its getting better. At the moment using the above module works the best and setting up my own styling for left float etc. I'm trying to get it so my client can use it intuitively and I don't think CKE is quite there yet in D8 ..

Comment: What version did you update from? D8.5 brought in Media module. New way:  https://www.webwash.net/managing-media-assets-using-core-media-in-drupal-8/ Old way: https://www.webwash.net/manage-media-assets-drupal-8/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted and answered on drupal.org https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2018-08-24/ckeditor-image-button-cannot-insert-images-in-body-of-a#comment-12854570

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Suggested by Tech-Tonic:

https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2018-08-24/ckeditor-image-button-cannot-insert-images-in-body-of-a#comment-12854570

> Does your content type have other file fields on it?
>   If so, try temporarily disabling all file/image fields for the content type in "Manage form display" and save. Then enable them again and save. Worked for me, in Drupal 8.6.3.

As mentioned above, I also had an image/file field in the content type. Under 'Manage form display', I disabled the image field and saved. I then went back to 'Manage form display', moved it back to where it originally was and saved again.

After this the error no longer appears. This worked on the production, staging and development copies of the same site.